# How to set specific user can run certain root command in redhat

Tags: linux, redhat

i want to ask for a specific user to use certain root commands in redhat?

my server run redhat OS 7.6. i dont have any idea how to set a user that can run certain commands from root.

let say i have one user id name MY_CIT, so  MY_CIT can run certain commands for example to create print queue #lpadmin -p printer -v socket://printer:9100 -E

so MY_CIT no need root access to trigger the command.

Anyone experience on this? kindly help. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run command with a root privilege:

```
sudo visudo
```

It opens file `/etc/sudoers` for edit.
Add this line at the end of the file (and after keep one blank line):

```
MY_CIT ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/lpadmin
```

where:

`MY_CIT` - name of your user
`/usr/sbin/lpadmin` - path to executible file. Note please that in your distro path can be different. You can check this with command `whereis lpadmin`.

After user can run command `lpadmin` with arguments with `sudo` without password:

```
sudo lpadmin ...
```

Comment: i try this it prompt password on local hosts. it is need to put the password in localhosts?

Comment: @den I have corrected path to file in my answer. It should be `/usr/sbin/lpadmin`. In your distro you can check path with command `whereis lpadmin`. Then login as `MY_CIT` and check again. Will `sudo lpadmin ...` request the password?

Answer (score 1):

You'll be able to use file ACLs. As a test I removed execute permissions from the nano command, just to show how this will work.

You won't need to do this, however, you will need root permissions to the machine. Instead of nano, use 'lpadmin' as per your requirements

```
[root@server bin]# chmod o-x /bin/nano 
[root@server bin]# ls -lah /bin/nano
-rwxr-xr-- 1 root root 202K Jun 10  2014 nano
```

To test, we change to user1 and try use nano to edit a file:

```
[user1@server ~]$ nano file1
-bash: /bin/nano: Permission denied
```

Now, as root again, we add an ACL to the nano program. This allows only user1 to execute the program.

```
[root@server bin]# setfacl -m u:user1:x /bin/nano
```

Display ACL with getfacl:

```
[root@server bin]# getfacl /bin/nano
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: bin/nano
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:user1:--x            <<-- Note this
group::r-x
mask::r-x
other::r--
```

As user1, we are able to use the nano program, but not as user2:

```
[user1@server ~]$ nano file1
[user1@server ~]$ ls
file1
[user1@server ~]$ exit
logout
[root@server bin]# su - user2

[user2@server ~]$ nano file1
-bash: /bin/nano: Permission denied
```

ACLs allow admins to extend permissions past just user/group/other. You're able to set permissions for specific users on the system.

Comment: As I understand, there are many system commands and programs required root privileges (`sudo`) for successful executing, for example `/bin/kill`. Therefore, described method will work not always.